# Object ready for Garbage collection, Java

Tags: java, garbage

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html#99740 example A3.3 says, it says that an object might still not be available for garbage collection even though it might be out of scope. IT is available only if the method is taked off stack. Now if we consider the following case:

```
void foo(){
Dog a = new Dog();
Dog b = new Dog();
b=a
while(true)//loop for long time
}
```

Will the object b referring to be available immediately for garbage collection, or only after the foo() method is returned.

Comment: You mean the object `b` was referring to initially, right, before it was re-assigned to the same object as `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack slot remains in use until the method exits. There is no JVM opcode corresponding to an inner }, so the JVM doesn't know it's gone out of the inner scope. But it does know when the method returns.

Comment: +1. and even though the stack slot remains in use, it will only ever hold the *last* object assigned to it. You can also set it to null if you cannot wait for the end of the method.

Answer (score 2):

The dog formerly knows as `b` should become eligible for garbage collection as soon as you re-assign the variable.

The dog known as both `a` and `b` (after that re-assignment) will remain in scope until the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

The original `b` (the second `Dog` created) is available immediately for garbage collection before the loop starts, because there is no reference held to it (both `a` and `b` reference the *first* `Dog` created).

Comment: if that is the case then in :public void run() {
    try {
        Object foo = new Object();
        foo.doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // whatever
    }
    while (true) { // do stuff } // loop forever
}why is that the object foo is available for Garbage collection only when run returns

Comment: @Jatin: I doubt that that is the case. All those orphaned foos will be collected.

Answer (score 0):

Except the correct answers already given, your test is essentially flawed. Running empty `while` loop will never trigger GC as it only runs (to simplify a bit) when you run out of memory and Java needs to do some cleanup of old objects.

Comment: by forever i mean while loop for a long time with block of code inside it. ie will the object be right away available or after the method returns

Comment: @Jatin: How could `a` or `b` be collected before the method returns? They are still in scope after all, could for example be used within the loop. (A clever compiler might find out if they are actually being used and shorten their scope, but as per your code, they have the same scope as the method).

Comment: so that basically means objects are available for garbage collection only when the method is returned? in this case a and b