# Make objects created inside loop available for GC in java

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

[Object ready for Garbage collection, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062212/object-ready-for-garbage-collection-java) says that an object becomes available for gc only when the function ends. So if I am creating objects inside a loop, how do I make sure they become available for gc even before the termination of the function
e.g

```
void foo{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    Object o = new Object();

    /*some operation*/
  }
}
```

Since there are many objects created inside the loop, I want the objects to get available for gc before the function ends.

Will making it null after use make it available for gc or will it have the same effect as above. e.g

```
   void foo{
      for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        Object o = new Object();

        /*some operation*/
        o = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever an object no longer has any references referencing it, it is available for gc. `o=null;` explicitly does this but shouldn't be necessary as `o` is local to the for loop scope.

Comment: Yes, but the question's link I have mentioned in my post says that it will not be available for gc until the method ends

Comment: @dilip It says nothing of the sort. Read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Object ready for Garbage collection, Java says that an object becomes available for gc only when the function ends.

No it doesn't. I wrote that answer, and it doesn't say any such thing.

What it actually says is that the *stack slot* remains until the function exits. In the case of your code, all the objects created inside the loop except the last one become unreferenced as soon as the next one is created, because the prior reference in the same stack slot is overwritten. See the comment by @Thilo, which says exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this test :

```
public long test(){
    long result = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<30_000;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<30_000;++j){
            Object obj1 = new Object();
            result = result ^ System.identityHashCode(obj1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am creating here around 879MB of data just for this function (16 bytes java.java.Object times 30_000 and then times 30_000 again).

I am running it with :

```
java -Xms40m -Xmx40m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails TestFunc
```

Giving it only 40MB of heap, means that it should crash if Java can't recollect the memory until the for loop does not finish, but that does not happen.

Instead you will see A LOT of lines like this:

```
[GC [PSYoungGen: 11088K->368K(13312K)] 11096K->376K(40960K), 0.0013320 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

This is a "minor" garbage collection call in the Young Generation.
Thus GC can and in fact will be triggered if you have memory pressure, and it does not matter if you have not finished you loop yet. If objects are not needed, they will be recollected.